React native DatePicker provide android error
I have an error that I can't understand because the error only occurs on Android
Here is the error:

ERROR TypeError: Unable to read property 'calendars' not set
This error is located at:
in CalendarHeader (created by DatePickerBody)
in RCTView
in Unknown (created by DatePickerBody)
in provider (created by DatePickerBody)
in DatePickerBody (created by DatePickerExample)
in Unknown
in ResetPresence
in RemoveScroll
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Animated(View))
in Animated(View) (created by PopperContent)
in ResetPresence (created by PopperContent)
in PopperContent
in RCTView (created by Stack)
in the pile
in Unknown
in Unknown (created by Animate)
in Animate
in Unknown
in RCTView (created by Stack)
in the pile
in provider (created by PopoverRepropagateContext)
in provider (created by PopoverRepropagateContext)
in PopoverRepropagateContext (created by PopoverContentPortal)
in Theme (created by PopoverContentPortal)
in RCTView (created by YStack)
in YStack (created by Portal)
in PortalHostComponent (created by PortalProviderComponent)
in PortalProviderComponent (created by TamaguiProvider)
in Theme (created by ThemeProvider)
in ThemeProvider (created by TamaguiProvider)
in Provider (created by TamaguiProvider)
in TamaguiProvider (created by TamaguiProvider)
in TamaguiProvider (created by RootLayoutNav)
in RootLayoutNav (created by RootLayout)
in RootLayout
in Try
in Unknown
in Unknown (created by Route())
pending (created by Route())
in Route (created by Route())
in Route() (created by ContextNavigator)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by wrapper)
in the wrapper (created by ContextNavigator)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in theme provider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (created by App)
in the application (created by ErrorOverlay)
in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
in ErrorOverlay (created by withDevTools(ErrorOverlay))
in withDevTools(ErrorOverlay)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main (RootComponent), js engine: hermes

import { useDatePickerContext } from '@rehookify/datepicker'
import type { DPDay } from '@rehookify/datepicker'
import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight } from '@tamagui/lucide-icons'
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { AnimatePresence, Button, View } from 'tamagui'
import { DatePicker } from './dateParts'
import {
  DatePickerInput,
  SizableText,
  YearPicker,
  YearRangeSlider,
  swapOnClick,
  useHeaderType,
  HeaderTypeProvider,
  MonthPicker,
} from './dateParts'

function CalendarHeader() {
  const {
    data: { calendars },
    propGetters: { subtractOffset },
  } = useDatePickerContext()
  const { type: header, setHeader } = useHeaderType()
  const { year, month } = calendars[0]

  if (header === 'year') {
    return <YearRangeSlider />
  }

  if (header === 'month') {
    return (
      <SizableText width="100%" ta="center" userSelect="auto" tabIndex={0} size="$8">
        Select a month
      </SizableText>
    )
  }
  return (
    <View
      flexDirection="row"
      width="100%"
      height={50}
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="space-between"
    >
      <Button circular size="$4" {...swapOnClick(subtractOffset({ months: 1 }))}>
        <Button.Icon scaleIcon={1.5}>
          <ChevronLeft />
        </Button.Icon>
      </Button>
      <View flexDirection="column" height={50} alignItems="center">
        <SizableText
          onPress={() => setHeader('year')}
          userSelect="auto"
          tabIndex={0}
          size="$4"
          cursor="pointer"
          color="$color11"
          hoverStyle={{
            color: '$color12',
          }}
        >
          {year}
        </SizableText>
        <SizableText
          onPress={() => setHeader('month')}
          userSelect="auto"
          cursor="pointer"
          tabIndex={0}
          size="$6"
          color="$gray12"
          fontWeight="600"
          lineHeight="$1"
          hoverStyle={{
            color: '$gray10',
          }}
        >
          {month}
        </SizableText>
      </View>
      <Button circular size="$4" {...swapOnClick(subtractOffset({ months: -1 }))}>
        <Button.Icon scaleIcon={1.5}>
          <ChevronRight />
        </Button.Icon>
      </Button>
    </View>
  )
}

export function useDateAnimation({ listenTo }: { listenTo: 'year' | 'month' | 'years' }) {
  const {
    data: { years, calendars },
  } = useDatePickerContext()
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [currentYearsSum, setCurrentYearsSum] = useState<number | null>(null)

  const sumYears = () => {
    return years.reduce((acc, date) => acc + date.year, 0)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (listenTo === 'years') {
      if (currentYearsSum !== sumYears()) {
        setCurrentYearsSum(sumYears())
      }
    }
  }, [years, currentYearsSum])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (listenTo === 'month') {
      if (currentMonth !== calendars[0].month) {
        setCurrentMonth(calendars[0].month)
      }
    }
  }, [calendars[0][listenTo], currentMonth])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (listenTo === 'year') {
      if (currentYear !== calendars[0].year) {
        setCurrentYear(calendars[0].year)
      }
    }
  }, [calendars[0][listenTo], currentYear])

  const prevNextAnimation = () => {
    if (listenTo === 'years') {
      if (currentYearsSum === null) return { enterStyle: { opacity: 0 } }

      return {
        enterStyle: { opacity: 0, x: sumYears() < currentYearsSum ? -15 : 15 },
        exitStyle: { opacity: 0, x: sumYears() < currentYearsSum ? -15 : 15 },
      }
    }
    if (listenTo === 'month') {
      if (currentMonth === null) return { enterStyle: { opacity: 0 } }
      const newDate = new Date(`${calendars[0][listenTo]} 1, ${calendars[0].year}`)
      const currentDate = new Date(`${currentMonth} 1, ${calendars[0].year}`)

      if (currentMonth === 'December' && calendars[0].month === 'January') {
        return {
          enterStyle: { opacity: 0, x: 15 },
          exitStyle: { opacity: 0, x: 15 },
        }
      }
      if (currentMonth === 'January' && calendars[0].month === 'December') {
        return {
          enterStyle: { opacity: 0, x: -15 },
          exitStyle: { opacity: 0, x: -15 },
        }
      }
      return {
        enterStyle: { opacity: 0, x: newDate < currentDate ? -15 : 15 },
        exitStyle: { opacity: 0, x: newDate < currentDate ? -15 : 15 },
      }
    }
    if (listenTo === 'year') {
      if (currentYear === null) return { enterStyle: { opacity: 0 } }
      const newDate = new Date(`${calendars[0].month} 1, ${calendars[0].year}`)
      const currentDate = new Date(`${calendars[0].month} 1, ${currentYear}`)

      return {
        enterStyle: { opacity: 0, x: newDate < currentDate ? -15 : 15 },
        exitStyle: { opacity: 0, x: newDate < currentDate ? -15 : 15 },
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    prevNextAnimation,
    prevNextAnimationKey: listenTo === 'years' ? sumYears() : calendars[0][listenTo],
  }
}

function DayPicker() {
  const {
    data: { calendars, weekDays },
    propGetters: { dayButton },
  } = useDatePickerContext()

  const { days } = calendars[0]

  const { prevNextAnimation, prevNextAnimationKey } = useDateAnimation({
    listenTo: 'month',
  })

  // divide days array into sub arrays that each has 7 days, for better stylings
  const subDays = useMemo(
    () =>
      days.reduce((acc, day, i) => {
        if (i % 7 === 0) {
          acc.push([])
        }
        acc[acc.length - 1].push(day)
        return acc
      }, [] as DPDay[][]),
    [days]
  )

  return (
    <AnimatePresence key={prevNextAnimationKey}>
      <View animation="medium" {...prevNextAnimation()}>
        <View flexDirection="row" gap="$1">
          {weekDays.map((day) => (
            <SizableText key={day} ta="center" width={45} size="$4">
              {day}
            </SizableText>
          ))}
        </View>
        <View flexDirection="column" gap="$1" flexWrap="wrap">
          {subDays.map((days) => {
            return (
              <View flexDirection="row" key={days[0].$date.toString()} gap="$1">
                {days.map((d) => (
                  <Button
                    key={d.$date.toString()}
                    chromeless
                    circular
                    padding={0}
                    width={45}
                    {...swapOnClick(dayButton(d))}
                    backgroundColor={d.selected ? '$background' : 'transparent'}
                    themeInverse={d.selected}
                    disabled={!d.inCurrentMonth}
                  >
                    <Button.Text
                      color={
                        d.selected ? '$gray12' : d.inCurrentMonth ? '$gray11' : '$gray6'
                      }
                    >
                      {d.day}
                    </Button.Text>
                  </Button>
                ))}
              </View>
            )
          })}
        </View>
      </View>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}

function DatePickerBody() {
  const [header, setHeader] = useState<'day' | 'month' | 'year'>('day')

  return (
    <HeaderTypeProvider type={header} setHeader={setHeader}>
      <View flexDirection="column" alignItems="center" gap="$2.5" maxWidth={325}>
        <CalendarHeader />
        {header === 'month' && <MonthPicker onChange={() => setHeader('day')} />}
        {header === 'year' && <YearPicker onChange={() => setHeader('day')} />}
        {header === 'day' && <DayPicker />}
      </View>
    </HeaderTypeProvider>
  )
}

/** ------ EXAMPLE ------ */
export function DatePickerExample() {
  const [selectedDates, onDatesChange] = useState<Date[]>([])
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(false)
  }, [selectedDates])

  return (
    <DatePicker
      open={open}
      onOpenChange={setOpen}
      config={{
        selectedDates,
        onDatesChange,
        calendar: {
          startDay: 1,
        },
      }}
    >
      <DatePicker.Trigger asChild>
        <DatePickerInput
          placeholder="Select Date"
          value={selectedDates[0]?.toDateString() || ''}
          onReset={() => onDatesChange([])}
          onButtonPress={() => setOpen(true)}
        />
      </DatePicker.Trigger>
      <DatePicker.Content>
        <DatePicker.Content.Arrow />
        <DatePickerBody />
      </DatePicker.Content>
    </DatePicker>
  )
}




I try to debug get the context but am new i dev

I ran into this as well, and added a workaround to this github ticket, namely, wrap the <DatePickerBody /> in another <DatePickerProvider>:

export function DatePickerExample() {
    const [selectedDates, onDatesChange] = useState<Date[]>([]);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
+   const dpConfig = {
+       selectedDates,
+       onDatesChange,
+       calendar: {
+           startDay: 1 as const,
+       },
+   };

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpen(false);
    }, [selectedDates]);

    return (
        <DatePicker
            keepChildrenMounted
            open={open}
            onOpenChange={setOpen}
-           config={{
-               selectedDates,
-               onDatesChange,
-               calendar: {
-                   startDay: 1,
-               },
-           }}
+           config={dpConfig}
        >
            <DatePicker.Trigger asChild>
                <DatePickerInput
                    placeholder="Select Date"
                    value={selectedDates[0]?.toDateString() || ''}
                    onReset={() => onDatesChange([])}
                    onButtonPress={() => setOpen(true)}
                />
            </DatePicker.Trigger>
            <DatePicker.Content>
                <DatePicker.Content.Arrow />
-               <DatePickerBody />
+               <DatePickerProvider config={dpConfig}>
+                   <DatePickerBody />
+               </DatePickerProvider>
            </DatePicker.Content>
        </DatePicker>
    );
}

